# Uri.EscapeUriString for ASP.net binding value

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a task to show live updating encoded URL. So I am taking user entered URL on the top input field and update it's encoded URL on bottom on time with key strokes in input field. But it didn't work.

**Input:**
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.url, new { @class = "form-ctrl", ng_model = "vm.url" })

**Show**

@Uri.EscapeUriString("{{vm.url}}")

**Actual Output**
Nothing

**Expected Output**
Encoded URL with each and every key strokes

Note:
But when I used

{{vm.url}}

, it will give live update. but it is not a encoded string. So can you please help me to get encoded value?

**Actual Output**
Nothing

**Expected Output**
Encoded URL with each and every key strokes

Note:
But when I used

{{vm.url}}

, it will give live update. but it is not a encoded string. So can you please help me to get encoded value?

Comment: Your use of the ng-model attribute, along with the {{vm.url}} suggests you might be using AngularJS on the front end.  `@Uri.EscapeUriString("{{vm.url}}")` is parsed on the back end, resulting in the blank output.  {{vm.url}} is parsed on the front end and replaced (on the front end) with the value.  In order to get the result you want (live updating of the url) you will have to work in the front end code and escape the url there.

Comment: but I have used these two in the view.

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.url, new { @class = "form-ctrl", ng_model = "vm.url" })
<h1>C: @Uri.EscapeUriString("{{vm.url}}")</h1>

Not working.

Comment: <h1>C: @Uri.EscapeUriString("{{vm.url}}")</h1> Output is: C: %7B%7Bvm.url%7D%7D

Comment: Look into Razor templates (parsed at the server, uses "@" to designate commands) and AngularJS templates (parsed in the browser, uses "{{" and "}}" to designate commands).  My guess is that you're using both and trying to fix the problem in the wrong place. (at the server, when you should be fixing it at the client side)

Comment: Thanks @Grax32, Got the point. These two different and can't get my output. I used filter for this and used it.
  
*JS*
  
websiteApp.filter("urlencode", ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return function (input) {
        return input ? window.encodeURIComponent(input) : "";
    }
}]);
  
  
View
  
<h1>{{vm.url | urlencode}}</h1>